# Python logging show 3 lines for 1 log in log file

Tags: python, logging

I have a python project where I have 3 python files out of which `app.py` is the main file and other two files are `tracker.py` and `celerio.py`. I have the logging enabled for all the files and below is its code:

```
def setup_logger(logger_name, log_file, level=logging.ERROR):
    log_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s')
    my_handler = RotatingFileHandler(log_file, mode='a', maxBytes=100 * 1024 * 1024, backupCount=5, encoding=None,
                                     delay=0)
    my_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
    my_handler.setLevel(level)
    l = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    l.addHandler(my_handler)

dir = Path(__file__).parents[1]
log_file = os.path.join(dir, 'logs', 'application.log')
setup_logger('debug', log_file)
log = logging.getLogger('debug')
```

and then I use it like `log.error("Hello world")` in the python file and it works fine. Now as I have another 2 files, I have also copied the same above code in those two files `tracker.py` and `celerio.py`. But the problem is, lets if I log `log.error("Hello world from app.py")` in `app.py`. It is saved as 3 times in `application.log` file. Same is the case with other files as well.

```
2019-11-15 13:32:00,288 Hello world from app.py
2019-11-15 13:32:00,288 Hello world from app.py
2019-11-15 13:32:00,288 Hello world from app.py
```

I dont know why it is logged 3 times for just 1 log. Can anyone please help me in this. Thanks

Comment: The line log = logging.getLogger('debug') is not in a function. So when you import those files, you import the reference to that. Hence calling log.error('whatever') prints three time. You can test this by removing it from one file and it will only log twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you set up your logger you add new handlers over and over again. Just try to clear them before adding:

```py
l.handlers[:] = []
```

Comment: So you mean before this line `l.addHandler(my_handler)`, I should add `l.handlers[:] = []`.?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Or you may check if you have already added a handler before.

Comment: I just want to add that you may want to consider setting all your logs configuration in one place (maybe via `logging.config.dictConfig`) and then set the `logging.initialized = True` (you create a logging module variable that is persistent for your Python session). Then you may check `if hasattr(logging, 'initialized')` to prevent from setting the configuration several times.

Answer (score 1):

The logging system has global state. By adding this code to all three of your modules, you are adding three handlers to the logger named "debug".

Only setup your logging once in `app.py`, only use `log = logging.getLogger('debug')` in your other modules.

**app.py**

```
def setup_logger(logger_name, log_file, level=logging.ERROR):
    log_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s')
    my_handler = RotatingFileHandler(log_file, mode='a', maxBytes=100 * 1024 * 1024, backupCount=5, encoding=None,
                                     delay=0)
    my_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
    my_handler.setLevel(level)
    l = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    l.addHandler(my_handler)

dir = Path(__file__).parents[1]
log_file = os.path.join(dir, 'logs', 'application.log')
setup_logger('debug', log_file)
log = logging.getLogger('debug')
```

**tracker.py and celerio.py**

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger('debug')
```